# Unity not accepting System.Numerics reference

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have been struggling to add `BigInteger` to my code in MonoDevelop to allow for very large numbers, however `System.Numerics` is giving me a lot of trouble. I have added the .dll reference, iv'e made sure everything else is referenced correctly, however I still get this error:

```
Assets/Scripts/Click.cs(4,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Numerics' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Here is the class that i'm trying to use Numerics with:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Numerics;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.UI.Text PixelsDisplay;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text PPC;
    public double pixels = 0.0;
    public double ppc = 1.0; 

    void Update(){
        PixelsDisplay.text = "Pixels: " + pixels.ToString ("#,#");
        if (pixels >= 10000000) {
            PixelsDisplay.text = "Pixels: " + Math.Round(pixels / 1000000, 2) + "M";
        }
        if (pixels >= 1000000000) {
            PixelsDisplay.text = "Pixels: " + Math.Round(pixels / 1000000000, 2) + "B";
        }
        if (pixels >= 1000000000000) {
            PixelsDisplay.text = "Pixels: " + Math.Round(pixels / 1000000000000, 2) + "T";
        }
        if (pixels >= 1000000000000000) {
            PixelsDisplay.text = "Pixels: " + Math.Round(pixels / 1000000000000000, 2) + "Qd";
        }
        if (pixels >= 1000000000000000000) {
            PixelsDisplay.text = "Pixels: " + Math.Round(pixels / 1000000000000000000, 2) + "Qt";
        }
        if (pixels >= BigInteger.Parse("1000000000000000000000")) {
            PixelsDisplay.text = "Pixels: " + Math.Round(pixels / BigInteger.Parse("1000000000000000000000"), 2) + "Sx";
        }

        PPC.text = "PPC: " + ppc.ToString ("#,#");
        //TODO
    }

    public void Clicked(){
            pixels += ppc;
    }
}
```

Now here is a picture showing all of my references:

[image]

I have searched for similar questions, but the answers given don't deal with System.Numerics directly and usually are not using MonoDevelop. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why not just use Mathf?

Comment: @Andrew because this is my first time working with large numbers in c#, so I am not 100% familiar with what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Try just doing exactly what you are doing but use `Mathf` in place of `Math`... its built into the Unity already i believe

Comment: That won't fix my issue though, MonoDevelop gives me an error with how big the number is if I don't use BigInteger.

Comment: check this out then http://biginteger.codeplex.com/ , also have you tried using `long`s or `ulong`s?

Answer (score 2):

`System.Numerics` is not implemented in the Mono flavor that Unity uses.

So you can't use that namespace. Keep in mind that the Mono that Unity uses is a custom one and is partly compatible with .NET 2.0.

MonoDevelop or VisualStudio will allow you to add the DLL needed and won't throw any erros, but Unity will.

Compatility list [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying in the classes you want, from https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource - it might devolve into copying/patching more and more files, or it could be fairly straightforward.  I got Complex.cs to work with only one or two changes.

Answer (score 0):

Including .DLLs into Unity is a small nightmare for beginners; the main reason being that Unity is several versions behind the current C# and .Net versions.

If you must include a .DLL, it can be done so long as the .DLL is referenced alongside all dependencies of the .DLL, and so long as all dependencies of those dependencies are referenced. If any dependency exceeds .Net Standard 2.1 or .Net Framework 4.7 (I think) then you will end up with compatibility issues.

That being said, this isn't impossible, its just a time consuming exorcise.

Steps to achieve what you want:

1. Place the System.Numerics.DLL into your project, ensuring that it is
   .Net Standard 2.0 or 2.1 compatible;
2. Locate the System.Numerics dependencies, iterate through each;
3. For each dependency, perform steps 1-3 in this list.

Assuming that they are all compatible, and all dependencies are included, Unity should be able to handle the .DLL as if it were compatible on its own.

The challenge you might face though, is "why" the .DLL is no compatible. If a sub-dependency has been excluded from Unity because of a copyright or licencing problem then you might run into legal issues and so forth.

For steps 1-3, you can typically find a list of dependencies on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors#dependencies-body-tab). This might not work for all .DLLs, but it will for most.